# Not able to log in to my SharePoint 2010 Site

Tags: 2010, error

I am not able to log in to my SharePoint 2010 Site...
It is showing following error:

An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information

Can someone help me out?

I was activated 'Search' just before this error came.

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your C2WTS (Claims to Windows Token Service) is running.